# How to save Huffman tree in file?

Tags: java, tree, huffman-code

I am working on Huffman coding in Java. I am not getting the point of how and where to store the tree. I know how to make the tree, and then save it as a binary file, but for decoding purpose we will again need that same tree to decode. How can I save that tree in a file to attach it with binary file?

Comment: Where is your code? Which programming language?

Comment: he said java if you paid attention

Comment: show some code you have tried for.

Comment: I am coding in java.

Comment: Can you plz give me some idea that how can I save tree in file so, it can be again used for decoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the tree as a series of bits: 0 represents a leaf, 1 represents an internal node. The output for a binary tree (Huffman or otherwise) with N leaf nodes and N-1 internal nodes will be a sequence of 2N-1 bits. (You can actually save two bits, since you know that the first and last nodes in the tree will be leaf nodes, but it's probably not worth complicating the algorithm to save two bits.)

Perhaps easiest is to arrange the bits in pre-order:

```
function write_tree (top_node) {
    if is_leaf(top_node) {
        write "0"
        // optionally, write any date associated with the leaf node
        // although in practice it's easier to write the leaf data
        // to a separate output stream. That lets this stream contain
        // actual bits rather than the characters "0"/"1"
        }
    else {
        write "1"
        write_tree (top_node.left)
        write_tree (top_node.right) }}

function read_tree (bit_stream) -> returns tree
    next_bit = bit_stream.read()
    if next_bit = "0" {
        root = new leaf
        // optionally read data associated with the leaf node
        }
    else {
        root = new internal node
        root.left = read_tree (bit_stream)
        root.right = read_tree (bit_stream) }
    return root }
```

I didn't notice at first that you mentioned Java, so I wrote the above in pseudo-code, which I'm sure you'll have no trouble re-writing in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i am not facing problem in building tree and assigning codes to characters. I am not understanding that how can we save tree in a file so that same tree can be used to decode the code? see the tree we are making is in our memory using linked list then how can we save it in a file?

Comment: But that's exactly what the code I gave you does! The sequence of bits precisely encodes the **shape** of the tree. Reading those bits lets you construct a new tree with exactly the same shape. Obviously the bits would be written to and later read from a file. In a Huffman tree, all internal nodes have valence 2 and all the data is attached to leaf nodes (which have valence 0). The data can be written separately in sequential order to a separate file or to another part of the same file, or as indicated interspersed with bits exactly where the corresponding leaf node is indicated.

Comment: sorry may be I don't understand your point. Thanks now I got it.